# How to secure/validate GET parameters

Tags: rest, api

The GET operation is about retrieving resource. And its perfectly fine but there are situations where you want e.g.

/:accountID/transactions

Now, assuming authentication & authorization is already there how can i assure that somebody will not gues :accountID of other user and get transactions which not belongs to their account?

Is there any solution besides back-end validation of accountID?

I cannot change from GET to POST also cannot use headers as the API is already defined and accepted by customer.

Answer (score 2):

You can create the **authentication** token to verify the request every time, while creating token you have to used the `username` or `userid` which represents the user in it.
Secondly while validating token you can check the `accountID` belongs to the user who's name/id is match else return error in response.
In this way there is overhead of matching the `accountId` to userid/name but it will solve your problem.
Cheers!!

Comment: Hi, thank you for quick response. By creating authentication token with usage of username you mean eg HMAC approach? If so i'm not able to do much as there is already token based authentication but without any relation to userID/name. Seems the only way is to do accountId validation on back-end services.

Comment: No I am not telling HMAC approach, instead when we use token based authentication we used to create token using one of the field i.e, userId/username so we will going to use the same and then validate the accountId with respect to userId. But as I mention it will be overhead for everytime

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try with custom hash logic to the account id. The same hash logic can use at server side to get the actual value. In this way, you may protect straight forward way of guessing account id by the user.

Note: I am suggesting above approach along with the back end account id validation.

for example: if account id : 1000 then hash it 9888 in server side map it back to actual values. (You can increase the complexity of hashing)